# The parent class css width property doesn't apply in child class @media queries

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have created two components in react project. In all components I have used **@media queries** Whenever I change screen sizes it has applied all @media queries styles in **Inspect tap**.

I have check individual components in **mobile** view and **desktop** and **tablet** view it works fine.

In my project ,I have used dropdown option it contains three value **Desktop**, **Tablet**, in **Inspect tap**.

**ISSUE:**
Whenever change dropdown values the parent class width will be changed while the child component **@media queries** doesn't apply in viewport.

ParentComponent:

```
<div className={cx('screen_view')}>
<div
 className={cx({
  desktop_view: screenView === 'Desktop',
  mobile_view: screenView === 'Mobile',
  tablet_view: screenView === 'Tablet',
})}>
<ChildComponent />
</div>
```

ParentComponent Style:

```
.screen_view {
 background-color: $color-concrete;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 margin: 94px 72px 94px 72px;
 }

 .desktop_view {
  width: 1024px;
 }

.tablet_view {
 width: 768px;
 }

.mobile_view {
 width: 320px;
 }
```

In ChildComponent, styles doesn't convert @media queries all styles has collapsed

I think the problem is the ParentComponent class **width** doesn't apply in viewport. Anyone know this issue kindly share your solution

Thank you...

Comment: I think I found the issue can you make thi live so I can experiment on it like on line edoter like https://stackblitz.com/or https://codesandbox.io/ etc

Comment: @PavanNagadiya  I have used many components and it's a big project i couldn't share code. can you share your approach i will test in local system

Comment: See your main mistake is you apply all classes you need to add conditions of the screen size and you apply class names accordingly like className={matchesSM ? styles.firstMainFoldForMob : styles.firstMainFold}

Comment: @PavanNagadiya I understand your explanations thank you... Actually I have applied '@mediaquery' in childcomponent. The Parent component inside child component has render   . i have change screen width in parent component. whenever change dropdown values the parent component screen width has change but child component '@mediaquery' doesn't apply